# What this does? return( makemove( makemove( st, "X"), "O" ))

Tags: python

Can someone in plain English explain what this function do?

```
conf=((("X", "X", "-"), ("O", "O", "-"), ("X", "X", "O")))


def makemove( conf_set, chr):
    new_conf_set = set()
    for config in conf_set:
        for i in range(0,3):
            for j in range(0,3):
                if config[i][j] ==  "-":
                  conf_as_list = [list(config[0]), list(config[1]), list(config[2])]
                  conf_as_list[i][j] = chr
                  new_conf_set.add((tuple(conf_as_list[0]), tuple(conf_as_list[1]), tuple(conf_as_list[2])))
    return new_conf_set

def next(conf):
    st = {conf}
    return( makemove( makemove( st, "X"), "O" ))
```

how it is executed? does it start from the most inner round bracket? and If I wanted to see more examples of functions like that, where should I look?

I have added the full code as requested. The functions return every possible functions of a tick tack toe game

```
assert next((("X", "X", "-"), ("O", "O", "-"), ("X", "X", "O"))) == \
{ (("X", "X", "X"), ("O", "O", "O"), ("X", "X", "O")),\
(("X", "X", "O"), ("O", "O", "X"), ("X", "X", "O")) }
```

Comment: 1- we have no clue what `makemove` is, 2- `next` is a python builtin and should not be used as variable name

Comment: We need to see more code to explain. If you need just basic info - yes, it's going mainly from inner to outter, from left to right.

Comment: The return value of `makemove(st, 'X')` is passed as a parameter to `makemove`, so it needs evaluating first.

Comment: We can't know exactly what it does if we don't see the code of the `makemove` function, but the order is: first, `makemove( st, "X")` is executed, and something is returned, call it `x`. Then, `makemove( x, "O" )` is executed, and the `next` function returns the result of that execution.

Comment: Without more context it is hard to say, but yes stuff gets executed from the innermost to outermost, from left to right.

Comment: I have added the full code, can someone write the same code without using the function inside another function. The aim is to output all possible configuration of the game given one configuration.

Answer (score 4):

The inner-most functions are executed first.

- `makemove( st, "X")` is executed, resulting in some value.
- This value is the first parameter in the function `makemove( makemove( st, "X"), "O" )`. This then again results in some value.
- This value gets returned from the `next` function. (Note: Do not use `next` as a variable name, as it overrides the default `next` function in Python)

`st` is `conf` wrapped in a set.

I must say, this code is very unusual. The spaces are off, the brackets after `return` are not needed, and you have not shown us what `makemove` is.